# Align and pad two similar text files for text comparison

Tags: c++, qt

I've to compare and highlight differences between two similar text files. I'm using QT 4.8 on VC2010 and C++ as programming language. After researching, I've found google [diff-match-patch library](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/.) which is available in QT platform.

I've been trying to align both the text files so that similar lines appear on the same line. Padding needs to be added by adding newline wherever appropriate on either left or right text.

Please suggest the best way based on diff match patch library and QT.